# Command failed: wait ${SUBPROC} on line 326

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create hadoop-cluster in GCP, by using below commands:

```
cd bdutil
$ ./bdutil -b [Bucket Name] \
-z us-east1-b \
-n 2 \
-P [Project-ID] \
deploy
```

...
At (y/n) enter y

---

Facing below issues, please help to resolve the issues:

```
Mon Oct  8 05:35:49 UTC 2018: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=geslanu-218716 --quiet --verbosity=info compute instances
 create geslanu-218716-w-0 --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --image-family=debian-8 --image-project=debian-cloud --netw
ork=default --tags=bdutil --scopes storage-full --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --zone=us-east1-b
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=geslanu-218716 --quiet --verbosity=info compute instances
 create geslanu-218716-w-1 --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --image-family=debian-8 --image-project=debian-cloud --netw
ork=default --tags=bdutil --scopes storage-full --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --zone=us-east1-b
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=geslanu-218716 --quiet --verbosity=info compute instances
 create geslanu-218716-m --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --image-family=debian-8 --image-project=debian-cloud --networ
k=default --tags=bdutil --scopes storage-full --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --zone=us-east1-b
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Command failed: wait ${SUBPROC} on line 326.
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Exit code of failed command: 1
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Detailed debug info available in file: /tmp/bdutil-20181008-053541-yeq/debuginfo.txt
Mon Oct  8 05:35:50 UTC 2018: Check console output for error messages and/or retry your command.
```

[image: atatched is the error log file]

Answer (score 1):

check next output - Detailed debug info available in file: /tmp/bdutil-20181111-105223-nET/debuginfo.txt

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.name': 'antonmobile_gmail-w-0'. Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9$
```

I am personally had an issue with UNIQUE_ID where used underscore. that does not conform with name restrictions.

PS: I know it is probably to late to answer but somebody else could have the same issue.